# Evaluating a sum (begginer)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am stuck on this evalutaion number.

So the sum is $$\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over (k+1)^2}-{1\over k^2}$$

I can't find a way :(. Do we use Comparasion or partial sums?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: $1^2 = 1$, perhaps you meant $(k+1)^2$ ?

Comment: Hint: Try and write out an expression for the sequence of partial sums.

Comment: Assuming $k+1^2$ was supposed to be $(k+1)^2$, the sum is telescoping.

Comment: $k=0$ is not good place to start,  the $\frac{1}{k^2}$ will make the calculator unhappy.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\ \left(\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} - \frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$

$S_1 = \frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{1^2}$

$S_2 =\left(\frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{1^2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)$

$S_3 = \left(\frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{1^2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4^2}-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)$

.

.

.

$S_n = -1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n\ \left(\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} - \frac{1}{k^2}\right)$

$\\$

From here you should be able to see what the sum goes to as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I was trying to leave something for the OP.

Comment: OK, comment deleted. OP, try to figure out how he got the general formula for $S_n$.

Comment: Well done!!  ... +1